# Node js Server High Ram Usage using Native cluster mode

Tags: node.js, ram

I'm new to Node Js in a production environment, we have a  Windows Server 2019 with 32GB ram / 8 Cores. Node Js processes are consuming too much memory and increasing and it doesn't goes down.

Also I modified the max-old-space-size using the following command, node --max-old-space-size=2048 server.js

[Server Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovLAx.png)

Comment: How many NodeJS processes are you spawning?

Comment: 16 processes are running, https://gist.githubusercontent.com/virgafox/a9df72fced6df18738a72aed76bdf531/raw/92a2458204d50cc55b403d3c84b090a542fb03ca/cluster.js im using this cluster to create the processors